# Why is $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)$ semisimple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $A$-module for $A$ a finite dimensional algebra. Let $\operatorname{rad}(M)=\bigcap\{N\subsetneq M\ \text{maximal}\}$. Clearly, $M/N$ is simple for any maximal submodule $N$. It seems to be standard that $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)$ is semisimple; however, I struggle to see this.

**My attempt:** In case of finitely many maximal submodules, this works out easily. Indeed, let $N, N'\subseteq M$ be submodules such that $M/N, M/N'$ is semisimple. Then $N/N\cap N'\cong (N+N')/N'\subseteq M/N'$, so as a submodule of a semisimple module, $N/N\cap N'$ must be semisimple itself, and the inclusion has a retraction $M/N'\to N/N\cap N'$.
The module $M/N\cap N'$ in question fits into an extension $0\to N/N\cap N'\to M/N\cap N'\to M/N\to 0$ of two semisimple modules. Additionally, there is a retraction $M/N\cap N'\to M/N\to N/N\cap N'$. Hence this extension splits, and $M/N\cap N'$ is a direct sum of semisimple modules.

**Question:** How to prove this for an arbitrary number of maximal submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct, as I explained in the comments.

The condition that $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra can be weakened a bit: we only need that $A$ is (left or right) Artinian.

The critical part is that $\mathrm{rad}(A)$ annihilates $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$  which is equivalent to saying that $\mathrm{rad}(A) M \subset \mathrm{rad}(M)$. (This is true without the Artinian condition)

Let $N \subsetneq M$ be a maximal submodule. Then $M/N$ is a simple module, so it is annihilated by $\mathrm{rad}(A)$, which means that $\mathrm{rad}(A)M \subset N$. Since this holds for any $N$, we get $\mathrm{rad}(A)M \subset \mathrm{rad}(M)$, so $\mathrm{rad}(A)$ annihilates $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$ which means that $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$ carries a canonical $A/\mathrm{rad}(A)$-module structure.

Now it is well-known that if $A$ is left or right Artinian, then $A/\mathrm{rad}(A)$ is a semisimple ring, so $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)$ is a semisimple $A/\mathrm{rad}(A)$-module and hence also a semisimple $A$-module.

Comment: Why is the semisimple $A/\operatorname{rad}(A)$-module $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)$ also semisimple as $A$-module?

Comment: Okay, I got it. If $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)=\bigoplus_i N_i$ as $A/\operatorname{rad}(A)$ module and $0\subsetneq N_i'\subsetneq N_i$ as $A$-module, $N_i'$ is also a nontrivial $A/\operatorname{rad}(A)$-submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a semisimple module is one which is a direct sum of (possibly infinitely many) simple modules.

Let $P:=\bigoplus M/N$ where the sum is taken over all (nontrivial) simple quotients $M/N$, and consider the natural map $M\rightarrow P$. The kernel of this map is exactly $\mathrm{rad}(M)$, so there is an embedding $M/\mathrm{rad}(M)\hookrightarrow P$.

Clearly $P$ is semisimple. Can you show that semisimplicity is preserved for submodules?

(There are several equivalent characterizations of semisimplicity: $P$ is a sum of simple submodules, $P$ is a *direct* sum of simple modules, and every submodules of $P$ is a direct summand.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sure, if $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)\subseteq P$ for $P$ semisimple, then any submodule $N$ of $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)$ is also a submodule of $P$ and thus has a retraction. The composition with $M/\operatorname{rad}(M)\to P$ then gives a retraction of $N\to M/\operatorname{rad}(M)$.

Comment: This argument is not complete. Without further justifications, we just have a map $M \to \prod M/N$, but a product of simple modules is not necessarily semisimple.

Comment: The condition that $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra has to be used in some form, as the statement is not true in general (consider $A=M=\Bbb Z$).

Comment: It seems to be an issue of nomenclature --- "semi-X module" often means "direct sum of X modules", and certainly this is a widespread convention. Adding chain conditions is secondary. My paranthesized note on equivalent characterizations of semisimplicity does not require chain conditions.

Comment: I see. I haven't doubted the existence of that map, but now that you question it, it becomes clear that there is no such map. @MatheinBoulomenos I'll think about your answer later.

Comment: @Ehsaan the issue is not about the fact that a semisimple module may be an infinite direct sum of semisimple modules. It's that the map $M \to \bigoplus M/N$ is not well-defined unless you can show that each $m \in M$ gets mapped to $0$ in all but finitely many quotients $M/N$. And as I have mentioned, you have not used that $A$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field anywhere, so your argument would equally apply to the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Z$ which satisfies $\mathrm{rad}(\Bbb Z) =0$, but is not semisimple